# Extract the base file name from a URL using bash

Tags: shell, string

```
url=http://www.foo.bar/file.ext; echo ${url##/*}
```

I expected this code to print `file.ext`, but it prints the whole URL. Why? How can I extract the file name?

Comment: Okay obv I am expecting the wrong things to happen.  Well I want to extract file.ext

Comment: You're trying to cut the end off the string? Try `dirname $url`. Or `grep -o 'http://[^/]*' <<<$url`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Because word has to match the string to be trimmed. It should look like:

```
$ url="http://www.foo.bar/file.ext"; echo "${url##*/}"
file.ext
```

Thanks derobert, you steered me in the right direction. Further, as @frank-zdarsky mentioned, `basename` is in the GNU coreutils and should be available on most platforms as well.

```
$ basename "http://www.foo.bar/file.ext"
file.ext
```

Comment: Hah, we both realize that at the same time. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 13):

To quote the manpage:

```
${parameter##word}
   Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
   a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
   the  beginning of the value of parameter, […]
```

`/*` does not match the beginning, because your URL starts with `h` not `/`.

A trivial way to do what you're looking for (according to your comment) is `echo "$url" | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev`. But of course, that'll give interesting results for URLs ending in a slash.

Another way to do what you want might be to use the pattern `*/` instead.

Comment: Glad you gave an explanation of what needs to be done and the quote from the manpage is a huge plus! That helped me a lot! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 10):

`basename`(1) works with URLs, too, so you could simply do:

```
url=http://www.foo.bar/file.ext; basename $url
```

Answer (score 4):

See also: [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing), though in this case the extended glob is not essential.

```
 shopt -s extglob; url=http://www.foo.bar/file.ext; echo ${url##+(*/)}
```

Output: `file.ext`